# Subsets of primes with unevenly distributed remainders mod 4

Tags: elementary-number-theory, distribution-of-primes

I am an undergrad math major and have been doing some research as a hobby. In short, I am looking at primes whose squares divide some number of the form $n^n + (-1)^n (n-1)^{(n-1)}$. I have found that for primes up to 800,000, about 55% of them are equivalent to 1 mod 4. I know there are theorems that prove that primes in general are evenly distributed across any modulus; more specifically, that the density of primes equivalent to a mod n is $\dfrac{1}{\phi(n)}$. I thought it was very odd that such a small but seemingly solid bias would appear in so random a place - does anyone know of similar subsets of primes where it has been proven/conjectured that some form of bias like this appears?

As requested by a comment, I am adding some information about these primes here (A283146 in the OEIS). As a means of ease of notation, let $X(n) = n^n + (-1)^n(n-1)^{n-1}$.

- For a given prime $p$, if $p^2 | X(n)$, then $p^2 | X(a)$ for all $a \equiv n \pmod{p(p-1)}$. A similar statement holds for non-divisibility, so that all solutions can be determiend by testing each residue class mod $p(p-1)$. Without listing the entire proof, this can be proven by simplifying $X(n+p(p-1)$ using the binomial theorem and using the Euler-Fermat Theorem to eliminate some coefficients. These simplifications show that $X(n+p(p-1)) \equiv X(n) \pmod{p(p-1)}$ independent of whether $p^2 | X(n)$.
- If $p^2 | X(n)$, then $p^2 | X(p(p-1) + 1 - n)$. That is, residue classes $a,b$ mod $p(p-1)$ that sum to 1 mod $p(p-1)$ either $p^2$ divides both $X(a)$ and $X(b)$ or neither. The proof for this statement uses a very similar approach to the first proof; it uses the binomial theorem to simplify $X(p(p-1) + 1 - n)$ and uses Euler-Fermat to deal with some leftover coefficients.
- There is a correspondence between consecutive $p$th powers mod $p^2$ and the values of $n$ for which $p^2 | X(n)$. It should be noted that the polynomial $f_p(x) = \dfrac{(x+1)^p - x^p - 1}{p} \mod{p}$ detects these roots. There is a generalization of this statement in the paper referenced in the OEIS article. This paper proves this statement by explicit construction of bijections between these, though I honestly am not enough of an expert to detail the proof here.
- It has been conjectured that the relative density of this set of primes within the primes is around 15%. This has followed from numerical evidence and a heuristic about the roots of $f_p(x)$ that I do not fully understand but are detailed in the paper I cite.
- If we let $\mathcal{C}_p = \{ n \in \mathbb{Z}_{p(p-1)}$ so that $p^2 | X(n) \}$, it is conjectured that $|\mathcal{C}_p|$ averages to 1 over the primes. This is a heuristic used in the cited paper and is explained using a probabalistic argument.

Any help would be much appreciated! Here is the link to the paper I reference

https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.5148

Comment: I don't know, 55% sounds about what I would expect looking at primes less than a million. I wouldn't try to predict what happens to that trend if you go up to a billion or higher.

Comment: See that's what I would normally think, but the primes themselves have already evened out to about 49.8% and 50.2% by then. I am more wondering if anybody is aware of any other sequences with a property like that so I could maybe get ideas for a more rigorous way to look at it.

Comment: Do you want to take a look at something like $n^2+n+41$, which is prime for small $n$s?

Comment: I'm not sure that would help. I am more wanting to know if any particular types of primes have been shown to disobey the "even distribution" of primes among different residue classes. An example of a type of positive answer that would be useful would be "Yes, Mersenne primes are skewed towards 1 mod 4 with a asymptotic density of 65%" (obviously not true but that's more the idea I am thinking about)

Comment: How do you check whether a prime divides some number of the form $n^n+(-1)^n\cdot (n-1)^{n-1}$ ? Not that I doubt it is possible, but it would be helpful to know how this works because it might enlight the structure of the primes you are looking for.

Comment: There is more structure with the values of $n$ than there are with values of $p$ for which $p^2$ divides these numbers. I am editting the original post to have some general information about the primes.

Comment: This expression is the discriminant of $x^n - x - 1$ (or something similar, that polynomial is from memory) and the idea was initially studied for the algebraic properties that would follow from a squarefree discriminant. I don't really know too much about that, I am studying these mainly as a sort of hobby and from a number-theoretical perspective.

Comment: I don't understand any of your assertions ($p^2 | X(a),a \equiv n \pmod{p(p-1)}$...) you should explain the argument behind them, or give a reference. Looking at the [oeis you mentioned](http://oeis.org/search?q=A283146&language=english&go=Search), it seems the starting point is [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.5148.pdf)

Comment: Yes - I authored that OEIS entry, that should be the right paper. I believe it was Section 3 of their paper that details the necessary steps in this proof, possibly some Lemmas from Section 2 were used. I would post my proof here but it is too algebraically cumbersome to be appropriate to post.