# solving of quadratic congruence

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

let  us suppose we have following  congruence equation

$${y^2}\equiv {a} \pmod {p}.$$

where  $p$ is prime,  i now that if for instance  $r$ is solution,  then $p-r$ is also solution , for instance

$${y^2}\equiv {10} \pmod {13}.$$

i  can check all possible starting  values of  $y$ , for instance

```
 >> y=1:12;
>> y=y.^2;
>> r=y-10;
>> find(mod(r,13)==0)

ans =

     6     7
```

which satisfies  given theorem, but is that  only solution method for prime $p$ ? i know when $p$ is composite , i can make  prime factorization   and solve  system using Chinese remainder theorem ,  but what  about  when $p$ is prime?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking ... are you asking whether there is a fast algorithm for solving a quadratic congruence $y^2\equiv a\pmod p$ when $p$ is prime?

Comment: no i have  just if there  is analytical solution  like  we are solving quadratic equation

Comment: No, there aren't continuous functions $\pmod p$, so analytic techniques aren't going to help. There are algorithms that are much better than brute force: for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli–Shanks_algorithm

Comment: aa i see  ok thanks  in advance , that is  exactly what i wanted

Comment: @GregMartin Hi, look at [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2222683/subsets-of-primes-with-unevenly-distributed-remainders-mod-4) about https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.5148.pdf